# Get value from custom attribute and pass it to controller. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have issue with get value from custom data attribute to controller. I want to console.log value from data-key attribute.

I tried use $attrs but is unknown,  please for hint or advice.

HTML:

```
<div class="offer-box" ng-repeat="offer in offers.offerDtoList">
              <div class="offer-box__headline">
                  <div class="offer-box__lp"><span class="number">{{ offer.spaceId }}.</span></div>
                  <div class="offer-box__title" ng-model="offerHeadline"><span>{{ offer.offerProduct }}</span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="offer-box__content">
                  <div class="offer-box__description">
                      <p>{{ offer.offerDetails }}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="offer-box__buttons">
                      <div class="btn btn-success" data="SPRZ" ng-click="sell( offer )" ng-model="sell">sprzedaj</div>
                      <div class="btn btn-info" data-key="ZAPL" ng-click="plan( offer )" ng-model="plan">zaplanuj</div>
                      <div class="btn btn-danger" data="ODRZ" ng-click="drop( offer )"  ng-model="drop">odrzuć</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

myApp.controller( 'AppCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', '$attrs', function ( $scope, $http, $attrs ) {
  console.log( 'Hello from controller!' );

$scope.proceed = function () {
    var selectedOption = $scope.selectedOption;

    console.log( 'Count fn() clicked' );
    $http.get( '/xxxx/memcached' ).success( function ( response ) {
      if (response) {
        console.log( 'You are in context, good luck! ' + '\n CIF: ' + response + '\n Selected val: ' + $scope.selectedOption );
        $http.get( '/xxxx/offers/' + selectedOption ).success( function ( response ) {
          $scope.offers = response;
          console.log( 'Got offers data I requested:\n' + response );
        } );
      }
      else {
        console.log( 'Please pick up a context!' );
      }
    } )
  };

$scope.plan = function( offer ) {

    console.log(  );      <-- Here I wannt to console.log value from clicked middle button.
  };
```

Comment: Try to remove ng-model "plan" from: <div class="btn btn-info" data-key="ZAPL" ng-click="plan( offer )" ng-model="plan">zaplanuj</div>

Comment: After remove shout I use attrs() again? I'v tried jQuery method but it is not ok i guess:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass arg like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-success" data="SPRZ" ng-click="sell( offer,$event )" ng-model="sell">sprzedaj</div>
```

In Js:

```
$scope.plan = function( offer,id ) {
    console.log( id.target.attributes.data.value );      
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code you are using ng-model and ng-click using the same name..

```
<div class="btn btn-info" data-key="ZAPL" ng-click="plan( offer )" ng-model="plan">zaplanuj</div>
```

Instead you can remove ng-model and try without changing anything on the controller.